# Redirect to different sites depending on user role

Tags: php

I am currently making a website for a customer and he wants to have a page for all subscribers and a page for admins when you are logging in. Right now I have a login script that looks like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query)) {
        $db_user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $db_user_email = $row['user_email'];
        $db_user_password = $row['user_password'];
        $db_user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
        $db_user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
        $db_user_role = $row['user_role'];
    }
    $password = crypt($password, $db_user_password);
    if($user_email === $db_user_email && $password === $db_user_password ) {
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $db_user_email;
        $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $db_user_firstname;
        $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $db_user_lastname;
        $_SESSION['user_password'] = $db_user_password;
        $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $db_user_id;
        header("Location: ../admin ");
    } 
    else {
        header("Location: ../index.php ");
    }   
}
```

But I want to make a script that either sends the user to subscriber if his $user_role is subscriber or admin if he's admin.

Comment: Why you are not adding another `if` condition for checking `user_role` value?

Comment: Now it is working with the admin just not the subscriber. Then it's just redirecting to index and staying there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your scenario, the solution is to change the ending part of the IF:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query)) {
    $db_user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $db_user_email = $row['user_email'];
    $db_user_password = $row['user_password'];
    $db_user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
    $db_user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
    $db_user_role = $row['user_role'];
}

$password = crypt($password, $db_user_password);
if($user_email === $db_user_email && $password === $db_user_password ) {
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $db_user_email;
    $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $db_user_firstname;
    $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $db_user_lastname;
    $_SESSION['user_password'] = $db_user_password;
    $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $db_user_id;
    if($db_user_role == 'admin') header("Location: ../admin");
    elseif($db_user_role == 'subscriber') header("Location: ../subscriber");
    die();
} 

header("Location: ../index.php ");
```

Comment: Thank you! :) i am kinda new to php so i'm not that sharp yet. But this worked!

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a if statement in the if statement checking if the credentials is right. I made this if statement:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_role'])) { 
if(isset($_SESSION['user_role']) == 'admin') 
{ 
header("Location: ../admin"); 
} else if(isset($_SESSION['user_role']) == 'subscriber')
{ 
header("Location: ../subscriber"); 
} 
} 
} else { 
header("Location: ../index.php ");
 } 
}
```

?>